# z3 ocaml binding has error n_is_null is not available

Tags: ocaml, z3

I clone the z3 prover from [github](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), then run

`python scripts/mk_make.py --ml
cd build
make
sudo make install
sudo make ocamlfind_install`

then I set the variables LD_LIBRARY_PATH and CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However, when require package Z3, or even I just follow the example in z3, it says

Error: The external function n_is_null is not available

So, what's wrong?

I'm using Linux, Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks to everyone. I can't solve this problem. I will try to use a python process to decide formulae first, then communicate with the process in ocaml. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: This message means that either libz3ml.so wasn't compiled correctly, or  that it can't be found. Note that on OSX LD_LIBRARY_PATH is called DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and the .so is called libz3.dylib. Ocamlfind should be able to resolve all of that though, there's an example invocation with ocamlfind in examples/ml/README

Comment: There no error and no warning during my build. But I can't find a lib named libz3ml.so, while there are libz3ml.a and dllz3ml.so. But they can't make it binding work.

Comment: Are you trying on the toplevel ? z3 doesn't work in the toplevel at the moment. Nothing to do about it except waiting for it to be fixed.

Comment: No, I just follow the README file in the ml example. It always says that n_is_null is not available...

Comment: Can you try the instructions [here](https://github.com/termite-analyser/opam-termite) and/or [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/3298#issuecomment-98394795) ?